# how to make flexible cropping of bitmap image in android ?

Tags: android, image, crop

In Android i created an application based on Camera. Now i going to customize the image which i taken by my camera application. When i cropping , it will cropped only Top_Left corner of the image. I have to crop any place in the image. Guide me.

Thanks in advance.

I Used this code ;

```
 Display d = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        int x = d.getWidth();
        int y = d.getHeight();

        bmp.setDensity(Bitmap.DENSITY_NONE);
        bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, x, bmp.getHeight());

        if (imViewAndroid != null){
            imViewAndroid.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Cropping there are many android libraries available to make flexible cropping of images. I was used **com.soundcloud.android.crop** libraries within my project and it works well.

Steps:

1. Download sound-cloud cropping tool libray from git hub.
2. Paste lib folder inside your project,
3. Add your Library class in setting.gradle file.
4. If it necessary, Add that library in Project structure->dependency->library->[Exact extension of sound cloud]
5. Make use of the methods of sound-cloud cropping class in your project as your wish.
6. Build the project.

Happy coding!!

Comment: ya it works, thanks sudharsan, really it gave head ache in my past 15 days. Now i having idea to loop my project